# tick data at specific time in daylight saving timezone

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, synology, groupwise-maximum

I have a Synology NAS mariadb has huge tick data. I want to create a table with price at `16:00 US/Eastern` everyday.

It is easy to get the table with ticks at `10:05 GMT` everyday without timezone consideration:

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP,
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP / 1000)) DATE,
    TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP / 1000)) TIME,
    PRICE 
FROM DATASET.TICK
WHERE
    # 10:05:00 <= GMT < 10:07:00
    MOD(TIMESTAMP, 86400000) >= 79500000
    AND
    MOD(TIMESTAMP, 86400000) <  79620000
GROUP BY DATE;
```

seem the easiest way is to use `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` then with `CONVERT_TZ(Timestamp, 'UTC', 'US/Eastern')`. But I have the command in my NAS.

```
-sh: mysql_tzinfo_to_sql: command not found
-sh: mariadb-tzinfo-to-sql: command not found
```

Since there would be no data between 17:00 and 18:00 in `US/Eastern`, I might come up with a dumb and slow way to do it (maybe not in mysql). But I wish to see if there is any smarter way of doing it in my setup via mysql?

**UPDATED v1:**

For the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql: command not found` issue. I have dealt with it with my Ubuntu machine.

Setup:

- Synology NAS (ssh, mariadb)
- Ubuntu machine (ssh, mysql-server-core-8.0, mysql client)

Steps:

1. copy `zoneinfo` directory from NAS to your machine: e.g.

`scp -r user@192.168.1.2:/usr/share/zoneinfo ~/Documents`

2. run the command in your machine and update the `mysql` database: e.g.

`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql zoneinfo | mysql -u root -h 192.168.1.2 -p mysql`

Now, `CONVERT_TZ()` can be used. Since 'US/Eastern' does not exist in timezone table, I had chosen `America/New_York` instead. So the straight conversion from my previous code became:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP,
    DATE(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP / 1000), 'SYSTEM', 'America/New_York')) DATE,
    TIME(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP / 1000), 'SYSTEM', 'America/New_York')) TIME,
    PRICE 
FROM DATASET.TICK
WHERE
    # 16:00:00 <= America/New_York < 16:00:05
    TIME(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP / 1000), 'SYSTEM', 'America/New_York')) BETWEEN CAST('16:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('16:00:05' AS TIME)
GROUP BY DATE, CODE
```

`TIME` column can show 16:00 everyday. Although this part is solved, this works only for a small table and I now suffer from

`error 1206: The number of locks exceeds the lock table size.`

I can see this conversion is tedious and inefficient. However, my best guess or next move is to add Timezone based Date and Time columns to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve the second problem at the same time.

You want the last entry before, say, `10:07:00`.  [Perhaps you meant 'pm'?]  That gets rid of the missing entry issue.  And the multiple entries in an artificial time range.

But it raises another ugly situation -- how to get not just the timestamp in that range and get it for every stock, but get the rest of each matching row.  That is a "groupwise-max" problem; see the tag I added.

Or see which of the *efficient* algorithms I describe in [*Groupwise-Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) will suit your situation best.  Note, you will need to add an `INDEX` for any solution, and *that operation* will take a bunch of time.

You mentioned DST, but let's get rid of that by simply asking for the last entry before `23:59:59` for each day.  This assumes that you want the "market close" and that there are no trades after the close.  And it does not care if [the stupid] Daylight Savings is in effect.